# Creating charts in Blazor

Tags: c#, charts, blazor-server-side

So basically I want to create charts with server-side blazor, I was searching around for some packages which would allow me to create charts. The problem being that they are all pretty expensive:

1. [telerik](https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/components/chart/overview)
2. [syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/blazor-components/blazor-charts)

The only free alternative which is also pretty good I found was ofc. [ChartJs](https://www.chartjs.org/), but it uses obviusly js which is not really the direction I wanted to go for.

So are there any 'good' Blazor chart libraries which are free and let me create the normal hand full of chart types e.g. area-charts, line charts, bar charts ... ?

Comment: "Find me a library" questions usually get closed here. But do type "blazor charts" in the nuget search box. You won't be able to avoid JS entirely.

Comment: Yea I know that, there is also a StackExchange site for this exact purpose, but the user-base is so low that your question won't get barely any views. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If you qualify for a free Syncfusion community license. Then all blazor components are available free of charge. https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To answer the question myself, [this](https://github.com/stsrki/Blazorise) is the library which looks the most promising and it is also free.

Answer (score 11):

There is also a specific ChartJS.Blazor package available for free, just a small NuGet package. And compatible with client-side and server-side Blazor applications.

- [ChartJS.Blazor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChartJs.Blazor/) package by Marius Muntean
- Or search for "ChartJS.Blazor" in NuGet Package manager in Visual Studio

*Note: The . is after ChartJS and before Blazor, not after Chart directly. Otherwise you won't find this package but all the other variations.*

Comment: Note: This is now unmaintained. This was abandoned by the original creator, and the maintainer until recently has been a new developer, still in college making lots of mistakes (his own admission). It's now abandoned again. I would not pursue this unless you are prepared to fork and maintain it yourself.

Answer (score 9):

[Plotly.Blazor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plotly.Blazor) is now another option.

> Plotly.Blazor is a wrapper for plotly.js.
> Built on top of d3.js and stack.gl, plotly.js is a high-level, declarative charting library. It ships with over 40 chart types, including 3D charts, statistical graphs, and SVG maps.
> plotly.js is free and open source and you can view the source, report issues or contribute on GitHub.

Answer (score 4):

There is also [Blazly](https://github.com/lqdev/Blazly) even though it doesn't seem to be much activity lately it is quite easy to adapt to specific needs.

Answer (score 4):

There are beautiful charts available on Blazorise.com. Please check them and give a try:

https://bootstrapdemo.blazorise.com/tests/charts

Answer (score 2):

You can find the library for bar chart, and lot of other components here:

[radzen.com](https://blazor.radzen.com/bar-chart)